# Proguard gives 'Exception in thread "Tasks limiter_1" java.lang.StackOverflowError'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-proguard

Gradle running with proguard is giving this error:

```
Exception in thread "Tasks limiter_1" java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.accept(ProgramMethod.java:73)
        at proguard.classfile.ProgramMember.accept(ProgramMember.java:125)
        at proguard.shrink.UsageMarker$MyNonEmptyMethodUsageMarker.visitCodeAttribute(UsageMarker.java:272)
        at proguard.classfile.attribute.CodeAttribute.accept(CodeAttribute.java:101)
        at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.attributesAccept(ProgramMethod.java:81)
        at proguard.classfile.attribute.visitor.AllAttributeVisitor.visitProgramMember(AllAttributeVisitor.java:95)
        at proguard.classfile.util.SimplifiedVisitor.visitProgramMethod(SimplifiedVisitor.java:92)
        at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.accept(ProgramMethod.java:73)
        at proguard.classfile.ProgramMember.accept(ProgramMember.java:125)
        at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.methodAccept(ProgramClass.java:526)
        at proguard.shrink.UsageMarker.markProgramClassBody(UsageMarker.java:109)
        at proguard.shrink.ShortestUsageMarker.markProgramClassBody(ShortestUsageMarker.java:60)
        at proguard.shrink.UsageMarker.visitProgramClass(UsageMarker.java:88)
        at proguard.shrink.ShortestUsageMarker.visitProgramClass(ShortestUsageMarker.java:36)
        at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.accept(ProgramClass.java:358)
        at proguard.classfile.ProgramField.referencedClassesAccept(ProgramField.java:90)
        at proguard.shrink.UsageMarker.markProgramFieldBody(UsageMarker.java:359)
        at proguard.shrink.ShortestUsageMarker.markProgramFieldBody(ShortestUsageMarker.java:76)
        at proguard.shrink.UsageMarker.visitProgramField(UsageMarker.java:290)
        at proguard.shrink.ShortestUsageMarker.visitProgramField(ShortestUsageMarker.java:36)
        at proguard.classfile.ProgramField.accept(ProgramField.java:71)
        at proguard.classfile.ProgramMember.accept(ProgramMember.java:125)
        at proguard.classfile.constant.RefConstant.referencedMemberAccept(RefConstant.java:126)
        at proguard.shrink.UsageMarker.visitAnyRefConstant(UsageMarker.java:529)
```

I have latest android gradle plugins and android sdk version.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?  I am having the same issue

Comment: @rleffler This is actually Space problem of Machine on which you are building app. I have not faced this issue after I started building using command line gradle. And whenever I build, I close all the programs running on my machine.

Comment: Thanks that worked!